# How to pass parms to onSuccess function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-admin

On react-admin I have an Edit element and want to to invoke a function on success.

```
 <Edit onSuccess= {onSuccess } {...props}>
// properties
</Edit>
```

The onSuccess function (on typescript):

```
   const onSuccess = () => {
   redirect(`/XXX/${id}`);
   refresh();
   }
```

My question is how to pass the id of the edited element?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
<Edit onSuccess= {(id) => onSuccess } {...props}>
// properties
</Edit>
```

const onSuccess = (id) => {
redirect(`/XXX/${id}`);
refresh();
}

Comment: @Ajay you don't need to pass the id `(here) => function(just pass it here)`

Answer (score 1):

```
<Edit onSuccess={() => onSuccess(id)} {...props}> // passing the ID
// properties
</Edit>
```

```
const onSuccess = (id) => { // reading the ID
   redirect(`/XXX/${id}`);
   refresh();
   }
```